# How can I read data's from .txt file in C?

Tags: c, file, structure

I want to read the information that I saved in txt file in the program I created. but when I want to do the reading process only the first line of student information by reading, for example, class 10 people are writing the same student information 10 times within the program. I'm doing the read operation in the for loop.

```
struct student{

char Name[30];
char Surname[30];
int StudentNumber;
int MathematicScore;
int EnglishScore;
int HistoryScore;
int BiologyScore;
int LiteratureScore;
int PhysicsScore;
int classNum;
int total;
float average;
```

};

/* Printing process */

```
FILE *fout;
fout = fopen("Mathematic Class.txt","w"); 

printf("Please enter student number of class : ");
scanf("%d", &x.classNum);

fprintf(fout, "Class Number : %d\n",x.classNum);

for(i=0; i<x.classNum; i++){

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Name : ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&x.Name);

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Surname : ",i+1);
    scanf("%s",&x.Surname);

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Number : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&x.StudentNumber);

    printf("Please Enter %d.Student Score : ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&x.MathematicScore);

    x.total = x.total + x.MathematicScore;

    fprintf(fout, "\nStudent Name : %s %s Student Number : %d Student Score : %d\n", x.Name, x.Surname, x.StudentNumber, x.MathematicScore);
}   

x.average = x.total / x.classNum;

fprintf(fout, "\n\nClass Average is : %f", x.average);

fclose(fout);



/* Reading process */



        FILE *fin;
    fin = fopen("Mathematic Class.txt","r");


    fscanf(fin, "Class Number : %d\n\n%s %s %d %d\n",&x.classNum, &x.Name, &x.Surname, &x.StudentNumber, &x.MathematicScore, &x.average);
    fclose(fin);            


    printf("Class Number : %d\n", x.classNum);

    for(i=0; i<x.classNum; i++){

        printf("Student Name : %s %s Student Number : %d Student Score : %d\n", x.Name, x.Surname, x.StudentNumber, x.MathematicScore); 

    }

    printf("\n\nClass Average is : %f", x.average);
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried a minimal example without the loops to get the necessary functionality? Have you tried `fscanf`?

Comment: You seem to be reading only one line and into an `x` (which is not shown). The only loop you show  loops over `classNum`, but the loop variant `i` is not used in the `for` block and the code would only print one record `classNum` times.

Comment: What is `x`? Please create a [mcve] to show us. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @crashmstr What should I use and how do I replace the for loop?

Comment: @NathanS. Are you sure do you look to the my code ?

Comment: You might also want to do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) on your reading program. What are you really doing in that loop?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude x is struct student x;

Comment: Then what is `struct student`? Again ***please*** create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I edit my code.

Comment: Step 1: add code to check for errors, including checking return values of all `scanf` calls. Trying to debug issues with possibly uninitialized or otherwise invalid values is pointless.

Comment: Because you told the computer to print the same thing over and over...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems that I see upon first look:

1. You only call fscanf() one time in the reading process.  If you want to read in data for multiple students, like it appears you're doing in the writing process, you need to call it once for each student to read that student's line from the file.
2. In your reading/printing process, you are printing the same data x.classNum times.